# How to make low priority attribute in manifest yield the attribute to high priority manifest in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a android library, I want to set up the `autoBackUp` logic in order to provide better user experience. I understand that it becomes default behavior after Android M, I also want to take care of previous APIs but subclassing [BackupAgent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgent.html).

Here is my library `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="mypackage">
    <application 
       android:allowBackup="true"              // feature 1
       android:backupAgent=".mBackupAgent"/>   // feature 2
</manifest>
```

Here is my test app `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.paypal.android.lib.riskcomponentsample" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"   // feature 1
    android:backupAgent=".test"   // feature 2
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
 </manifest>
```

These manifests caused merge conflict since they got the same attributes.

Since it is inside a **library scope**, I can only modify the `AndroidManifest.xml` in the SDK (low priority). I don't have access to application level (high priority). I want to specify the attribute in the manifest, but how can I do this without potential conflict when the [merge logic](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#merge_conflict_heuristics) happen?

For example, if any of higher priority manifest has the same attribute, then I will yield the attribute to higher priority ones. But if there is no, then I want the application to take my attribute.